How do you write a typed nil in Swift?
I have a situation where I have to return a typed nil.
The only way I know of to "make" a typed nil is ..
// need to return String nil
var x: String? = nil
return x

..
// need to return Thing nil
var x: Thing? = nil
return x

is there a simpler way to write that?

Clearly (based on your cases) there is something going on here that you are not telling us. If there were not, it would be trivial to write func typedNil<T>(forType: T.Type) -> T? { nil }. Example, typedNil(forType: String.self) gives a nil String, and so on for any type at all.

Ah!  That's absolutely the answer.  What a great utility function.  So just to be totally clear there's no let's say built in syntax (picture something like "String.nil") .. ?

"there is something going on here..." ?  Hmm, hard to see how it could be clearer: "The only way I know of to "make" a typed nil is..." and "is there a simpler way to write that".  From your comment answer it appears the answer is "No, there is not" unless ".. but here's a natty utility function" - !

My reasoning is simply that if the function I suggested (or something like it) was satisfactory, you would be using it and would not have posed the question. Therefore, based on that fact and on the curious case .string etc., I deduce that you're using an enum with associated values or similar, which you have not shown us. In which case the question that you asked may not be the question to which you really want an answer.

That makes sense. @matt I removed the extra example code. (The case, enum, etc was utterly irrelevant, as it said "example...".)  As it says, the only way I knew of to create a type nil is with two lines of code "var x: String = nil; return x"

You are missing indication that these are optional, i.e., that they can be nil. E.g., var x: String = nil should be var x: String? = nil. In answer to your question, if you are returning an optional value, then type of the return statement is dictated by the function in question. E.g., func foo() -> String? { return nil }, where the type of the returned optional is dictated by the function signature, and no “type” is required at the return statement, itself.

@Rob "You are missing indication that these are optional" you know what, that was just a confusing typo when I typed in the question .. fixed!  TY

(I had an annoying case of dealing with some [Any?] , but later each index constrained to one of a selection of types by business logic only at runtime, and hence you can imagine preferring to return SomeThing nil rather than Any nil in those cases. Json sucks :) ) Hence from your example in the comment just there more like func someLowLevelFunction() -> Any? { return nil  .. but prefer typed nil depending on the flexible case at hand }

To return a nil Optional for any type whatever, you can use a generic function:
func typedNil<T>(forType: T.Type) -> T? { nil }

Example:
typedNil(forType: String.self) // yields a `nil` String

...and so on for any type you care to name. If you don't want to have to know the type of the object, i.e. if you just want "a nil like this object I'm holding", you don't need T.Type, just T:
func typedNil<T>(forTypeOf: T) -> T? { nil }

Example:
let something = "howdy"
/// ... and then later on ...
typedNil(forTypeOf: something) // yields a `nil` String


Optional is just an enum with 2 cases
enum Optional<Wrapped> {
    case some(Wrapped)
    case none
}

nil is just syntactic sugar for the none case. To explicitly specify the type of a nil, you can just access the none case in the same way as any other enum.
Optional<String>.none

String? is sugar for Optional<String>, so this can be even shorter:
String?.none

The as operator can also specify the target type for nil, so
nil as String?

is yet another way.

lol had utterly no clue, whatsoever, about the four points mentioned in this answer! :O
